# How to make a node property immutable in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, immutability

I have a neo4j database (community edition), in which I set a constraint for uniqueness in a property which I call 'uid' paired with a label :USER.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:USER) ASSERT user.uid IS UNIQUE
```

I would like, however, to protect this property in a way that no change can be made to it after a node is created, but still be able to change other properties. How can one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Neo4j constraints documentations](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/), has no way to do this out of the box. I believe that to achieve this goal you will need to make use of the Neo4j Java API and write a custom [user defined procedure / function](https://neo4j.com/developer/procedures-functions/).

Take a look in the GraphAware [Neo4j UUID library](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) for inspiration. According to the docs:

> Neo4j UUID library is a simple library that transparently assigns a
>   UUID to newly created nodes and relationships in the graph **and makes
>   sure nobody can (accidentally or intentionally) change or delete them.**

You can see an unit test for this requirement on [this source code](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid/blob/20e2c35d526c85a19bab1c41813d633755384cc6/src/test/java/com/graphaware/module/uuid/UuidModuleEmbeddedProgrammaticTest.java#L262).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there currently is no such thing in Neo4j.

There is a feature request (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2554)

You could try to enforce the immutability by writing custom user defined procedures or functions.